# Kotlin: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-adapter, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler view and a custom adapter, I have the adapter attached but I get "No adapter attached; skipping layout"

```
    timetableRecyclerView?.apply {
    layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)
    // set the custom adapter to the RecyclerView
    adapter = timetableAdapter
    }
```

And here is my Time table adapter, I call the populate method on a call back on my activity which populates the data

```
 fun populate(timetable: Timetable) {
        timetableList.add(timetable)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val row = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.timetable_row, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(row)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val (type, status, departure, arrival, airline, flight) = timetableList[position]



        viewHolder.airline!!.text = airline.name

        viewHolder.flightNumber!!.setText(flight.number)
        viewHolder.status!!.text = status

        when (status) {
            "active" -> {
                viewHolder.status!!.text = StringUtils.capitalize(status)
                viewHolder.flightDepartureStatus!!.setImageResource(R.drawable.green_dot)
                return
            }
            "landed" -> {
                viewHolder.status!!.text = StringUtils.capitalize(status)
                viewHolder.flightDepartureStatus!!.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_dot)
                return
            }
            else -> {
                viewHolder.status!!.text = StringUtils.capitalize(status)
                viewHolder.flightDepartureStatus!!.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_dot)
                return
            }
        }

    }
       override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return timetableList.size
    }


  }
```

Comment: From the code you posted it is not clear what `timetableAdapter` is. Post some more code to let us understand how and when it is created.

Comment: @gpunto please see edited.

Comment: Where is `timetableAdapter` assigned? It is not in the code you posted

Comment: @gpunto here     adapter = timetableAdapter

Comment: I meant where is `timetableAdapter = ...`? From the pieces of code you posted the flow is not clear. Can you post the activity/fragment where you are using `timetableAdapter`? The one that contains `timetableRecyclerView?.apply`

Comment: here timetableAdapter = TimetableAdapter(timetableList, this)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29141729/recyclerview-no-adapter-attached-skipping-layout

Comment: Did you debug the application? Are `timetableRecyclerView` and `timetableAdapter` not null and adapter contains items?

Comment: Are you sure that `timetableRecyclerView` is not null when you call `apply`?

Comment: Hi @CoolMind the recyclerview was null as i was trying to use butterknife

Comment: Hi @lelloman the recyclerview was null as i was trying to use butterknife

Answer (score 0):

the Recyclerview was null because I was trying to use Butterknife, I have been doing Kotlin for a week now and it has not been easy.

Comment: Stop using ButterKnife and use synthetic view imports https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html

Comment: @ZUNJAE, agree.